# What is some intermediate or advanced macroeconomics textbook use general approach and focus on general topics?

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request

What is some intermediate or advanced macroeconomics textbook that use general approach, cover major formulas, math intense and focus on general topics similar to Romer's and Branson's Macroeconomics book?

Instead of being use more specific approach like Macroeconomic Theory: A Dynamic General Equilibrium Approach?

Foundations of Modern Macroeconomics by Ben and Lectures on Macroeconomics by Blanchard are both good, what else are out there and how would you compare those two of four i mentioned with your choices in your answer? I know that a graduate economics textbook that teach general topics tend to be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you had a look at Dornbusch and Fischer's Macroeconomics? I would say that is a great book for both Introductory and Intermediate Macroeconomics. It emphasises on basic concepts (I used a really old edition but it still worked for me!) does a review after each section, the formulas are crystal-clear (I may be speaking only of myself though and I apologize in advance), brings up mathematical verification only occasionally, and there is nothing that the diagrams do not explain.

In addition, I used Greg Mankiw's Macroeconomics (still do) to run through topics- it covers most concepts and does not intimidate the reader at any point, but it is not so heavy on the math.

I do not have much idea as to what topics are covered under advanced Macroeconomics, but do take a look at these.